# How to avoid nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

my current project is making a diary app, where users can log in and post their articles to which comments can be linked. So the very natural way of implementing this project is something like

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
end

Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end

Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :article
end
```

However, rails guide says the resources should never be nested more than one level. With this relationship, how can I avoid using two-level nested resources?

Comment: The rails guide also tells you how to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources part 2.7.2 Shallow Nesting. E.g.:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments, shallow: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this you need to use `Shallow Nesting`. The rails guide has the complete tutorial on how to do that. Also there are many questions on stackoverflow related to that. Here are some links:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

[When using shallow routes, different routes require different form_for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772588/when-using-shallow-routes-different-routes-require-different-form-for-arguments)

[Rails 4 [Best practices] Nested resources and shallow: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868544/rails-4-best-practices-nested-resources-and-shallow-true)

https://railsforum.com/topic/1431-best-practices-nested-resources-and-shallow-true/

If you still get any issue implementing that then you should ask on stackoverflow.